# In text mode space being taken away

Tags: symbols

Why does the space after `\AA` disappear?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
5 \AA wavelength
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since extra spaces don't achieve anything in LaTeX, what can be done besides forcing a space?  Also, why is this symbol causing this affect?

Comment: This is independent of the symbol, but a default behaviour of TeX - to gobble spaces after an argumentless control sequence.

Comment: @Werner so the space has to be forced then?

Comment: ...you can use `\AA{}`, then you don't technically *force* the space.

Comment: You should use `siunitx` for units, and the problem will disappear: `\SI{5}{\angstrom}`